# SQL - substring query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have table with the following columns

```
  log_id      INT PRIMARY KEY 
  emp_name    VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
  date_log    VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL
  in_am       VARCHAR(8) NULL
  out_am      VARCHAR(4) NULL
  total_am    VARCHAR(4) NULL
  in_pm       VARCHAR(4) NULL
  out_pm      VARCHAR(8) NULL
  total_pm    VARCHAR(4) NULL
  grand_total VARCHAR(4) NULL
  id          INT  Foreign key here
```

Supposed I already get the value of in_am and out_am and I want to get the difference between it I did this.

```
 select cast(out_am as datetime) - cast(in_am as datetime) from Table
```

The result is like this:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:07.000
```

But I want this result

```
00:00:07
```

I try to substring it like this:

```
select substring((cast(out_am as datetime) - cast(in_am as datetime)),15,20) from table
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two dates to find time difference in SQL Server 2005, date manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521434/how-to-compare-two-dates-to-find-time-difference-in-sql-server-2005-date-manipu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the DATETIME format of 108 to output HH:MM:SS as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), (CAST(out_am AS DATETIME) - CAST(in_am AS DATETIME)), 108) FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using convert(time,getdate())

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values are always less than a day, you can cast the difference to `time`:

```
select cast(cast(out_am as datetime) - cast(in_am as datetime) as time)
from Table;
```

Alternatively, you can convert to a string and extract the time component:

```
select right(convert(varchar(255), cast(out_am as datetime) - cast(in_am as datetime) ), 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) :

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(CAST(out_am AS DATETIME) - CAST(in_am AS DATETIME) AS TIME), N'hh\:mm\:ss')
FROM TABLE
```