# how to calculate total hours between two dates row wise in php

Tags: php, mysql

> How to find the total hours between two dates row wise. I have a
>   table named as activity which contains five columns as
>   id,date,time,entry_type  (0 Means out , 1 Means In) and eid.

In **time column** we have both the Intime and Outtime of the employee respectively. how to  display both the Intime and Outtime separately of the respective employees.

**Activity Table Strucuture**

```
id   Date       time       entry_type    eid 
1  2017-04-14  01:31:47     1            2  
2  2017-04-14  02:31:47     0            2  
3  2017-04-14  02:35:47     1            2  
4  2017-04-14  02:55:60     0            2  
5  2017-04-14  03:00:00     1            2
```

I need the output as below:

```
   id   Date       In time    Out Time   Total Hours 
    1  2017-04-14  01:31:47   02:31:47     ?           
    2  2017-04-14  02:35:47   02:55:60     ?         
    3  2017-04-14  03:00:00
```

Comment: follow the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521434/how-to-compare-two-dates-to-find-time-difference-in-sql-server-2005-date-manipu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two dates to find time difference in SQL Server 2005, date manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521434/how-to-compare-two-dates-to-find-time-difference-in-sql-server-2005-date-manipu)