# How to find date difference in Number of months,Weeks,Days in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For Example I need date difference for

1.DECLARE  @lDFROM DATE = '2016-12-01',@lDTO DATE = '2018-05-31'

**Result :**

```
18 noofmnth,
0 nofweek,
0 noofdays
```

2.DECLARE  @lDFROM DATE = '2016-12-31',@lDTO DATE = '2018-05-25'

**Result :**

```
17 noofmnth,
3 nofweek,
4 noofdays
```

Comment: use `DATEDIFF` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two dates to find time difference in SQL Server 2005, date manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521434/how-to-compare-two-dates-to-find-time-difference-in-sql-server-2005-date-manipu)

Answer (score 0):

use datediff

```
select DATEDIFF(wk,'2016-12-01','2018-05-31')+1
```

Comment: I have tried like this..but cant get exact answer,SELECT DATEDIFF(mm,@lDFROM,@lDTO)   noofmnth,
    DATEDIFF(WW,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,@lDFROM,@lDTO),@lDFROM),@lDTO) nofweek,
    DATEDIFF(DD,DATEADD(WW,DATEDIFF(WW,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,@lDFROM,@lDTO),@lDFROM),@lDTO), DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,@lDFROM,@lDTO),@lDFROM)),@lDTO) + 1 noofdays